# Disable axes scale in Matlab

Tags: matlab

When I use *ginput*  to mark tqo points it is followed by updating the axes scales. How can I stop the "auto-scaling" of the axes in Matlab?

Code:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
grid on;

message = sprintf('Select two points for a line.');
uiwait(helpdlg(message));

[x, y] = ginput(2);
Xorigin1 = x(1);
Xorigin2 = x(2);
Yorigin1 = y(1);
Yorigin2 = y(2);

plot([Xorigin1,Xorigin2],[Yorigin1,Yorigin2], 'b-', 'LineWidth',2);  
hold on;
plot([Xorigin1,Xorigin2],[Yorigin1,Yorigin2], 'r+', 'LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize', 12);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the x- and y-axis are by default set to automically rescale their limits whenever data in the figure is changed.

You can overwrite this using

```
xlim manual
ylim manual
```

Comment: Do I have to give value to them?

Comment: No, literally just write `xlim manual` (and/or `ylim`). Of course if you specify limits for your axis (for example `xlim([0, 1])`) the automatic scaling is also turned off.